# What is wrong with my .net routes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I have followed a few tutorials online and they all seem to show the same logic for .net routing using ASP.net web forms.  When I execute the URL below I get a 404 error.  Test.aspx is in the root folder of this application.

http://www.mydomain.com/member/abc

Here is my global.asax contents:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "TestABC",
            "member/{name}",
            "~/Test.aspx");
    }               

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>
```

Is there something I need to do with my web.config file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the global.asax by yourself? Why are there script tags in there?

Comment: I right clicked on my project in solution explorer and added a new item.  I selected a global.asax file and that's what it gave me.  How should it be changed to work correctly?

Comment: what .NET version and mvc version are you using?

Comment: It is not an MVC model.  Web forms version 4.0.

Comment: My bad, misread that. Apparently you can use the script tags version of the global.asax to avoid using a codebehind file. So that should be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your routing module is not triggered when you hit the iis server.
As a test to verify that this is the cause : change your webconfig to run all managed modules upon a request.
You need to set this :

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

If that solved it you can go read [this resource](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) on why to not do that :)

Comment: That worked!  Thank you very much.  I also followed the resource provided which also worked.  Thank you for all of your help.